# unable to integrate ngx-uploader module with angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the ngx-uploader module with my angular 2 application but i keep getting the error below. I also got the similar errors when using other libraries like angular2-image-upload.i'm new to angular2 so i don't really understand the error.
[image: error]

Comment: Could you provide some code where you are using ngx-uploader?

Answer (score 0):

first. you must create an input element of type file:

```
<input #uploader  accept=".txt, .zip, .rar" type="file" #myUploader ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

then in your component (typescript file) import ng2fileselect module:

```
import { FileUploader, FileUploaderOptions} from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
```

then in ngOnInit method place this code

```
const options = {
        url: yourUploadURL,
        isHTML5: true,
        autoUpload: true,
        queueLimit: 1,
        allowedMimeType: yourallowedMimeType,
        maxFileSize: yourmaxFileSize
      };
      const uploader = new FileUploader(options);
```